# How to unregister broadcast receiver from an Application Class?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-application-class

I register broadcast receiver in Android's Application Class,but now my question is where to unregister that broadcast ?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 

{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
     ..... 
     // OTHER INITIALIZATIONS
     initNetworkBR();
} 
private void initNetworkBR() {

      br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        ....
      };
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
      filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
      registerReceiver(br, filter);
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should register the broadcast in manifest?

Comment: You can no longer use the manifest for CONNECTIVITY_ACTION in OREO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One suggestion is in your launcher activity or desired activity unregister that like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ((MyApplication) getApplication()).unregisterReceiver();
}
```

And implement `unregisterReceiver` method in `MyApplication` class:

```
public void unregisterReceiver() {
     unregisterReceiver(br);//your broadcast
}
```

Comment: I am not registering broadcast in Activity , I register in Application class.

Comment: OK, I will use it.

Answer (score 1):

Except using Broadcast Receiver in Application class you can Use a Base class for all your Activities. And register BR in the Base Activity then provide call backs to the childs.
As Activity has a strict lifecycle model so its better to use Runtime Broadcast receivers in Activity rather than Application class .

```
 public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //registerReceiver Here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //unregisterReceiver here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, that listen all callbacks from activities lifecycle. It can replace the suggestion to use a Base Activity using inheritance and in other hand use composition to resolve this problem.

You implement `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` interface in a class and in on create from your application class register the callback as continue:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(<here your typed class with ActivityLifecycleCallbacks>)
```

Then, you have full control over al activities lifecycle to do something like unregister or register receivers.

I hope it can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

As @Naruto Uzumaki mentioned above you can deregister it on the `onDestroy` method of Application.
But it's always a better option to use Broadcast Receiversin Activity instead of whole Application.

You can use the below approach to use it in Activity:-

```
public class DetailsActivity {

private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mNetworkReceiver = new NetworkReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
 }
```

Here is the way to unregister it.

```
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterNetworkChanges();
 }

 protected void unregisterNetworkChanges() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mNetworkReceiver);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver) in your onPause() to unregister the Broadcast receiver.

**Example:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private final BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new SmsBR();

  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);
  }

  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);
  }
}
```

Comment: Android novice here, but not too sure why the -1 here... This worked for me to clear the leaky receiver I had set up. The straight reference to mybroadcast in the unregisterReceiver function is what I was unsure about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `LocalBroadcastManager` to register and unregister  receiver instead of `BroadcastReceiver`.

[Benefits to use LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code :
  if you have registered from Manifiest.xml

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, MyReceiver.class);

    int status = context.getPackageManager().getComponentEnabledSetting(component);
    if(status == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED) {
     context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED , PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    }
```

If programmatically registering reciever :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
```